# Add and subtract from two list following if-else condition in Python

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

Here is what I have tried

```
c = ['8781' ,'2740', '1413', '3060', '5074']
d = ['8853' ,'2812', '1355', '2986', '5107']

start = map(int, c)
end = map(int, d)

for n,m in zip(start,end):
    if n < m:
        preS = map(lambda x:x-21, start)
        preE = map(lambda x:x+20, end)
        print (preS, preE)
    else:
        preS = map(lambda x:x-20, end)
        preE = map(lambda x:x+20, start)
        print (preS, preE)
```

Here my else part of loop is not executing and I got multiple lines of same output. Whats wrong here? 
I am expecting in following way:

`preS  preE
 8760  8873
 2719  2832
 1433  1335
 3080  2966
 5053  5127`

I get the following output:

```
  ([8760, 2719, 1392, 3039, 5053], [8873, 2832, 1375, 3006, 5127])
  ([8739, 2698, 1371, 3018, 5032], [8893, 2852, 1395, 3026, 5147])
  ([8719, 2678, 1351, 2998, 5012], [8913, 2872, 1415, 3046, 5167])
  ([8719, 2678, 1351, 2998, 5012], [8913, 2872, 1415, 3046, 5167])
  ([8718, 2677, 1350, 2997, 5011], [8913, 2872, 1415, 3046, 5167])
```

I would really appreciate for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating and printing the whole result lists in each iteration. The result from the last iteration "wins", and all elements in the result from the earlier iterations are overwritten.

Instead, you need to handle the elements individually, and only print the result once at the end:

```
preS = []
preE = []
for n, m in zip(start, end):
    if n < m:
        preS.append(n - 21)
        preE.append(m + 20)
    else:
        preS.append(n - 20)
        preE.append(m + 20)
print preS, preE
```

The whole thing can be expressed more concisely by a list comprehension:

```
preS, preE = zip(*[(n - 21, m + 20) if n < m else (n - 20, m + 20)
                   for n, m in zip(start, end)])
```

It uses the `zip(*list)` idiom to transpose the list of pairs.

Comment: ([8760, 2719, 1433], [8873, 2832, 1335])

([8760, 2719, 1433, 3080], [8873, 2832, 1335, 2966])
I get above output

Comment: You seem to have the print statement inside the loop. Move it out of the loop.